# Is there a way to get my geolocation for iOS decives with react native when developing on a Ubuntu device?

Tags: ios, react-native, ubuntu, geolocation, cocoapods

I am currently trying to get my geolocation in react native for an app.
The problem is that i have a Ubuntu device and all libraries for geolocation require for iOS to work that you run `pod install` inside of the `ios` folder. As i have a Ubuntu device that is not possible.

Is there any other way to get my geolocation for iOS devides in react native while still developing on Ubuntu?

Comment: You are going to need macOS at some point to build your iOS app

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @Paulw11 why is that? I thought react native was capable of developing iOS without the need of a mac.

Comment: @Iva what about my question is not specifying the problem correct? It was simply: Can i use geolocation for iOS in react native when developing on ubuntu.

Comment: Regardless of what language or environment you develop in, you ultimately need Xcode and its toolchain to build your app for iOS.  This toolchain is not available for any other platform